# How to get closest date compared to an array of dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012891/how-to-get-most-recent-date-from-an-array-of-dates) almost answered this question for me, but I have a specific need and didn't find what I sought there. This lies right outside my experience; couldn't quite wrap my head around it, so all I really need is a point in the right direction.

Let's say I have an array as follows:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> "2013-02-18 05:14:54" 
    [1]=> "2013-02-12 01:44:03" 
    [2]=> "2013-02-05 16:25:07" 
    [3]=> "2013-01-29 02:00:15" 
    [4]=> "2013-01-27 18:33:45" 
}
```

I would like to have a way to provide a date ("2013-02-04 14:11:16", for instance), and have a function determine the closest match to this in the array (which would be "2013-02-05 16:25:07" in this case).

I'd appreciate any tips. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I may not have the best naming conventions, but here goes.

I calculate the intervals between the array of dates and the given date. I then do a sort, to find the "smallest" difference.

```
$dates = array
(
    '0'=> "2013-02-18 05:14:54",
    '1'=> "2013-02-12 01:44:03",
    '2'=> "2013-02-05 16:25:07",
    '3'=> "2013-01-29 02:00:15",
    '4'=> "2013-01-27 18:33:45"
);


function find_closest($array, $date)
{
    //$count = 0;
    foreach($array as $day)
    {
        //$interval[$count] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
        $interval[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
        //$count++;
    }

    asort($interval);
    $closest = key($interval);

    echo $array[$closest];
}

find_closest($dates, "2013-02-18 05:14:55");
```

Comment: I ended up taking a second look at my code and worked up a solution. When I came back to check this thread, our code was nearly identical! Marking this as a solution since it's exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: Aha! You should check SO more frequently when you ask a question :)

Comment: I should and usually do. A rare lapse, it seems. Also, I've actually noticed your code is just a touch cleaner, so I adopted it instead. Thanks!

Comment: and what if there are 2 dates with the same diff?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question perfectly then this will solve your problem.

#### Tested Code

```
<?php
    $dates = array
    (
        '0' => "2013-02-18 05:14:54",
        '1' => "2013-02-12 01:44:03",
        '2' => "2013-02-05 16:25:07",
        '3' => "2013-01-29 02:00:15",
        '4' => "2013-01-27 18:33:45"
    );

    function closest($dates, $findate)
    {
        $newDates = array();

        foreach($dates as $date)
        {
            $newDates[] = strtotime($date);
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($newDates);
        echo "</pre>";

        sort($newDates);
        foreach ($newDates as $a)
        {
            if ($a >= strtotime($findate))
                return $a;
        }
        return end($newDates);
    }

    $values = closest($dates, date('2013-02-04 14:11:16'));
    echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $values);
?>
```

Comment: what about closest previous date ?. How can we find closest previous date from this array /

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your array is bigger and that you have dates over the period `2009-10-01` to `2019-10-01`. Lets now compare two approach: a. `looping-array approach` vs b. `sorting-indexing-array approach`.

```
<?php 

$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2009-10-01 00:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('P3D'),
    new DateTime('2019-10-01 00:00:00')
);

foreach($period as $date){ 
    $dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
};


$today = '2019-08-18 13:00:15';

function custom_sort($array){
  sort($array);
  return $array;
}

function nearest_date_key($array, $today){
    //push today to the array, sort the array, 
    //find the nearest day value of the sorted array and return key
    array_push($array, $today);
    $sorted_dates = custom_sort($array);
    $find_today_key = array_search($today, $sorted_dates);
    $nearest_date = array_slice($sorted_dates, $find_today_key + 1, 1);
    return array_search($nearest_date[0], $array);
}


function find_closest($array, $today)
{
    //$count = 0;
    foreach($array as $day)
    {
        //$interval[$count] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
        $interval[] = abs(strtotime($today) - strtotime($day));
        //$count++;
    }

    asort($interval);
    $closest = key($interval);
    return $closest;
}

$start = microtime(true);
$result_a = nearest_date_key($dates, $today);
$time_elapsed_secs_a = microtime(true) - $start;

$start = microtime(true);
$result_b = find_closest($dates, $today);
$time_elapsed_secs_b = microtime(true) - $start;
?>
```

Printing the results gives (http://phptester.net/)

```
                            result  time_elapsed
loop approach (a)           1203    0.00630   
sorting index approach (b)  1203    0.00062
```

Which is a huge time elapsed **gain**. We divided by ten the waiting time

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$date = array(
    [0]=> "2013-02-18 05:14:54"
    [1]=> "2013-02-12 01:44:03"
    [2]=> "2013-02-05 16:25:07"
    [3]=> "2013-01-29 02:00:15"
    [4]=> "2013-01-27 18:33:45");

$baseDate = date_create('2009-10-11');
$count = count($date);
for($loop=0;$count>$loop;$loop++) {
    $datetime = date_create($date[$loop]);
    $interval = date_diff($baseDate, $datetime);
    $newDate[$interval->format('%s')] = $date[$loop];
}
ksort($newDate);
foreach($newDate as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value;
    break;
}
```

Your first element will the the closest match date.

Note: Please test it before you use.

Comment: I really appreciate the assistance! After testing, "echo $value;" always seems to return the last result in the array.

Comment: @Jon that is what i have given break over there.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi your code is always comes with 2013-02-12 01:44:03 as output no matter if we change the date.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me think of a solution to my similar problem, so am dropping it here.

Given an array of dates, I needed to find the closest date, before or equal, to last Sunday.

Here's what I did without using any custom functions:

```php
$all_dates = [
  '20210328',
  '20210321',
  '20210314',
  '20210307',
];
$last_sunday = date( 'Ymd', strtotime( date( 'Ymd' ) . 'last sunday')); //20210321
$latest_date_index;

foreach( $all_dates as $index => $date ) {
  $date_obj = date_create_from_format( 'Ymd', $date );
  $last_sunday_obj = date_create_from_format( 'Ymd', $last_sunday );

  if ( $date_obj <= $last_sunday_obj ) {
    $latest_date_index = $index;
    break;
  }
}

echo "latest date from array: $all_dates[$latest_date_index]";
echo "array of all past dates from array: " . var_dump(array_slice($all_dates, $latest_date_index));
```

Answer (score 0):

this way also you can get sorted datetime array

```
function order_date_time($date_times=array(),$compare=null,$action=1){
    $interval=0;
    $order_date_time=array();
    if(empty($date_times)){
        return array();
    }

    foreach ($date_times as $date_time) {
        $interval = strtotime($compare)-strtotime($date_time);
        $order_date_time[$interval]=$date_time;
    }
    if(empty($compare)){
        krsort($order_date_time);
        return isset($order_date_time) && !empty($order_date_time)?array_values($order_date_time):array();   
    }else{
        $order_date_time=array_values($order_date_time);
        $compare_index=array_search($compare,$order_date_time);
        return $order_date_time[$compare_index+$action]??$order_date_time[$compare_index];
    }
}
```

//input

```
  $array=array
    (
        2022-02-23 19:58:00
        2022-03-02 18:00:00
        2022-02-09 18:00:00
    )

$close_dat_time=order_date_time($array,'2022-02-23 19:58:00')
```

// output

```
2022-02-09 18:00:00
```