# Show closest date with name

Tags: php

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016725/how-to-get-closest-date-compared-to-an-array-of-dates-in-php) post, there is an answer that shows the following code:

```
<?php
$dates = array
(
    '0' => "2013-02-18 05:14:54",
    '1' => "2013-02-12 01:44:03",
    '2' => "2013-02-05 16:25:07",
    '3' => "2013-01-29 02:00:15",
    '4' => "2013-01-27 18:33:45"
);

function closest($dates, $findate)
{
    $newDates = array();

    foreach($dates as $date)
    {
        $newDates[] = strtotime($date);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newDates);
    echo "</pre>";

    sort($newDates);
    foreach ($newDates as $a)
    {
        if ($a >= strtotime($findate))
            return $a;
    }
    return end($newDates);
}

$values = closest($dates, date('2013-02-04 14:11:16'));
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $values);
```

Instead of showing the date, how can I show the number? In this case: 2.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why Person 2? Closest to what?

Comment: @M.Ginkel, `Person 1` is closest to today

Comment: This is a very broad question, would you mind editing this question so it is actually understandable for other viewers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate nearest `key` of given date value

```
$arr =['0' => "2013-02-18 05:14:54",
'1' => "2013-02-12 01:44:03",
'2' => "2013-02-05 16:25:07",
'3' => "2013-01-29 02:00:15",
'4' => "2013-01-27 18:33:45"];
$date = "2013-02-04 14:11:16";
$near = "";
$lowest = 0;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  $diff = abs(strtotime($date)-strtotime($value));
  if(!$lowest || $diff < $lowest) {
    $near = $key;
    $lowest = $diff;
  }
}
print_r("Nearest key is : $near");
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/872057

Output will be For

`2013-02-04` => `2` // its near to date `2013-02-05`

`2013-02-06` => `2` // again its near to date `2013-02-05`

Comment: Thanks man! Is it possible to change the $date to the current date?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob at PHP. How do I change it in the code so it shows the closest date compared to today? Thanks.

Comment: You're the best! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = array ( "2017-10-25 01:44:03", "2017-10-20 05:14:54",
"2017-12-05 16:25:07",  "2017-11-15 02:00:15");

function find_closest( $array, $date ) {
    foreach($array as $day)
    {
        $interval[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
    }

    asort($interval);

    $index = array_keys($interval, min($interval)); 

    $closed_bday_index = $index[0];

    echo "Person".$closed_bday_index." b'date ".$array[ $closed_bday_index ];
 }

find_closest($dates, "2013-02-18 05:14:55");
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Output: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'person_id' (T_STRING)

Comment: Its due to comments, try now and show me your thumb if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array
(
    '0' => "2013-02-18 05:14:54",
    '1' => "2013-02-12 01:44:03",
    '2' => "2013-02-05 16:25:07",
    '3' => "2013-01-29 02:00:15",
    '4' => "2013-01-27 18:33:45"
);


function find_closest($array, $date)
{
    //$count = 0;
    foreach($array as $day)
    {
        //$interval[$count] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
        $interval[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
        //$count++;
    }

    asort($interval);
    $closest = key($interval);

    echo $array[$closest];
}

find_closest($dates, "2013-02-04 14:11:16");
```

Comment: Output is '2013-02-05 16:25:07'

Comment: Yes, but I want to display the number, so that should be '2'. (;

Answer (score 0):

You have to just return the key of your array.

```
$dates = array
(
    '0' => "2013-02-18 05:14:54",
    '1' => "2013-02-12 01:44:03",
    '2' => "2013-02-05 16:25:07",
    '3' => "2013-01-29 02:00:15",
    '4' => "2013-01-27 18:33:45"
);

function closest($dates, $findate)
{
    $newDates = array();

    foreach($dates as $date)
    {
        $newDates[] = strtotime($date);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newDates);
    echo "</pre>";

    sort($newDates);
    foreach ($newDates as $key=>$a)
    {
        if ($a >= strtotime($findate))
            return $key;
    }
    return $key;
}

$values = closest($dates, date('2013-02-04 14:11:16'));
echo  $values;
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1361182494
    [1] => 1360651443
    [2] => 1360099507
    [3] => 1359442815
    [4] => 1359329625
)
2
```

Comment: This doesn't work so well. If you pass the date `2013-01-28` it returns `1` rather than `3` https://3v4l.org/C3cSl