# PHP get closest time to given array of times

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, difference, php-carbon

I have an array called `$timeslots` with timeslots like:

```
array:32 [▼
  0 => "2018-12-15T12:00:00.0000000"
  1 => "2018-12-15T12:15:00.0000000"
  2 => "2018-12-15T12:30:00.0000000"
  3 => "2018-12-15T12:45:00.0000000"
  4 => "2018-12-15T13:00:00.0000000"
  5 => "2018-12-15T13:15:00.0000000"
  6 => "2018-12-15T13:45:00.0000000"
  7 => "2018-12-15T14:15:00.0000000"
  8 => "2018-12-15T14:30:00.0000000"
  9 => "2018-12-15T14:45:00.0000000"
  10 => "2018-12-15T15:00:00.0000000"
  11 => "2018-12-15T15:15:00.0000000"
  12 => "2018-12-15T15:30:00.0000000"
  13 => "2018-12-15T15:45:00.0000000"
  14 => "2018-12-15T16:15:00.0000000"
  15 => "2018-12-15T16:45:00.0000000"
  16 => "2018-12-15T17:00:00.0000000"
  17 => "2018-12-15T17:30:00.0000000"
  18 => "2018-12-15T17:45:00.0000000"
  19 => "2018-12-15T18:30:00.0000000"
  20 => "2018-12-15T18:45:00.0000000"
  21 => "2018-12-15T19:15:00.0000000"
  22 => "2018-12-15T19:45:00.0000000"
  23 => "2018-12-15T20:15:00.0000000"
  24 => "2018-12-15T20:45:00.0000000"
  25 => "2018-12-15T21:00:00.0000000"
  26 => "2018-12-15T21:15:00.0000000"
  27 => "2018-12-15T21:30:00.0000000"
  28 => "2018-12-15T21:45:00.0000000"
  29 => "2018-12-15T22:00:00.0000000"
  30 => "2018-12-15T22:15:00.0000000"
  31 => "2018-12-15T22:30:00.0000000"
]
```

Also, I have a variable like:

```
$expected_time = 2018-12-15T18:00:00.0000000; // this can be different value, so its not unique value
```

$expected_time is never into array `$timeslots` but I need to find closest value to $expected_time... How I can do that?

How I can get the closest timeslot value from array `$timeslots` to `$expected_time` and calculate the difference in minutes?

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be fairly simple to write a `foreach` loop and calculate the differences

Comment: No, its not just the difference. I know to do that, problem is to find the closest value to give $expeted_time ... so $expected_time can be different each time

Comment: As a hint, if you convert these values to timestamps you can then find which two in the array that the expected time is between. You can then pick the appropriate slot based on any criteria.

Comment: Can you explain **why** it is no problem to compute the difference, but a problem to find the element with minimum distance?

Comment: @JonJ give me nice idea with timestamp. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: yes, once you have the timestamps, it's a simple loop to find the smallest  absolute value of A-B.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016725/how-to-get-closest-date-compared-to-an-array-of-dates-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nico mentioned in the comments, it's pretty straightforward. Just looping and calculating the time difference.

```
$timeslots = [...];
$expected_time = "2018-12-15T18:00:00.0000000";
$timestamp = strtotime($expected_time);
$diff = null;
$index = null;

foreach ($timeslots as $key => $time) {
    $currDiff = abs($timestamp - strtotime($time));
    if (is_null($diff) || $currDiff < $diff) {
        $index = $key;
        $diff = $currDiff;
    }
}

echo $timeslots[$index];
```

Comment: I would move the `strtotime($expected_time)` outside the loop and make it a variable. The way you do it you will parse the date 31 times more than needed based on the array in question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution fitting your requirements:

```
function findClosestDate($expectedDate,$dates)
{

    $differenceInMinutes = null; 
    $expectedDate = new DateTime($expectedDate);
    $expectedDateEpoch = $expectedDate->getTimestamp();
    $returnIndex = -1;

    for($i = 0; $i<count($dates); $i++)
    {
        $dateObject = new DateTime($dates[$i]);
        $dateEpoch = $dateObject->getTimestamp();
        $difference = abs($expectedDateEpoch-$dateEpoch);
        $difference = $difference/60;
        if($differenceInMinutes === null || $difference < $differenceInMinutes)
        {
            $differenceInMinutes = $difference;
            $returnIndex = $i;
        }
    }

    return array(
        "closest" => $dates[$returnIndex],
        "difference" => $differenceInMinutes
    ) ;
}
```

This makes use of the `DateTime` class to create a `DateTime` object and get the respective `timestamp`. The minutes are then calculated by the absolute difference between the `expectedDate` and the entry in the `dates` array. After iterating over the whole array, the closest match and the difference is returned in one array.

Answer (score 1):

as your list is already sorted - u can put the element into array and use sort again - and it will be much faster then calculating the diff in each iteration.

```
<?php
$timeslots = [
    ...
];

$expected_time = "2018-12-15T18:00:00.0000000";
$counter = count($timeslots);
$timeslots = array_flip($timeslots);
$timeslots[$expected_time] = $counter;
ksort($timeslots);

while (key($timeslots) !== $expected_time) {
    $prev = key($timeslots);
    next($timeslots);
}

next($timeslots);
$next = key($timeslots);

$expected_time = new \DateTime($expected_time);
$closestDiff = min(($expected_time)->diff(new \DateTime($prev)), (new \DateTime($next))->diff($expected_time));
var_dump($closestDiff->i);
```

Comment: Why not array_search instead of looping?

Comment: I need the prev and the next of the current - it's better to work with that on doublelinkedlist - but we have an array:)