# How to sort dates from closest date to the furthest in an array of dates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016725/how-to-get-closest-date-compared-to-an-array-of-dates-in-php) answered this question but I didn't understand the answers very well

I have an array contains dates,

I want to sort column `date_res` (**results date**) by the closest to today not the greatest or the smallest

my array may help you

```
<?php 
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$arr = array(
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'date' => '2020-03-27',
        'date_end' => '2020-05-02 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2020-06-02'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'date' => '2020-04-27',
        'date_end' => '2020-06-02 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2020-08-02'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '3',
        'date' => '2020-06-27',
        'date_end' => '2020-07-02 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2020-08-02'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '4',
        'date' => '2021-01-01',
        'date_end' => '2021-02-01 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-03-01'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '5',
        'date' => '2021-02-01',
        'date_end' => '2021-03-01 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-04-01'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '6',
        'date' => '2021-05-01',
        'date_end' => '2021-06-01 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-08-01'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '7',
        'date' => '2021-02-06',
        'date_end' => '2021-01-29 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-01-29'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '9',
        'date' => '2021-04-27',
        'date_end' => '2021-05-03 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-05-03'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '10',
        'date' => '2021-02-01',
        'date_end' => '2021-02-06 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-05-03'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '11',
        'date' => '2021-02-02',
        'date_end' => '2021-02-07 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-05-05'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '12',
        'date' => '2021-03-27',
        'date_end' => '2021-02-07 17:00',
        'date_res' => '2021-06-02'
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: How should dates before today be handled?

Comment: @John Hanley, it will be changed from date to a link , Because after date of the result ends , the results will appear and have a link

Comment: That is not my question. Your question states `sort` by closest to today. Is yesterday the same as tomorrow in your sort routine?

Comment: OP seems to want the absolute difference/distance between today and date_res ordered from smallest to largest. With yesterday and tomorrow being equal distance apart.

Comment: I don't know but I think if you but yasterday in the same routine there is no problem , beacause yasterday will be hidden ,  @John Hanley

Comment: What shall be the output (structure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the **differences** of the `date_res` entries to `today`:

```
usort($arr, function($dateA, $dateB) use ($today) {
    return
        abs(strtotime($dateA['date_res']) - strtotime($today)) -
        abs(strtotime($dateB['date_res']) - strtotime($today));
});
```

The `abs` is used to get the "distance" between `date_res` and `today` regardless if its before or after. Then you just compare the "distances".

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/8Z1k2).

### References

- [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [abs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try (note that I converted the date_res column to date in `sort_dates` function as it was string):

```
function sort_dates($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x['date_res']) - strtotime($y['date_res']);
}
usort($arr, "sort_dates");
```

[Tested it](https://paiza.io/projects/dqjYOlXZ8u-LSfIgvdmU2g) and I get the desired output using the array you provided.

Comment: I tested it and it works for me with the same array you provided.

Comment: are you sure from this code, cuz I think the problem in my code that I added you code in it

Comment: I ll try it in another way

Comment: I edited the question and linked to code and output to show that it works.

Comment: This answer fails the criteria: `closest to today not the greatest or the smallest` You are just sorting on `date_res`.